# Can a single USB/IP export both gadgets and physical bus devices? If not, can 2 instances of USB/IP run simultaneously?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel-modules

I need to create USB gadgets for a keyboard and mouse and attach them to a client using USB/IP. I also need to attach a few other devices.

USB/IP can run in Device Mode (using the `-e` or `--device` flag) which would create a UDC for the gadgets I want to bind to the USB/IP service. However, the language makes it clear that it won't "drive an attached device". If I don't use Device Mode, can I bind the gadget to the driver the same way I would bind physical devices?

If not, is it possible to run 2 instances of USB/IP? One for the gadgets in Device Mode and one regular?

If I can't do that, is it possible to write my own USB/IP server application that enables both modes at once?